# CSS/jQuery animation not triggering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I'm trying to use an animation, triggered by changing the class in jQuery on page load. It currently isn't doing anything. I'm unsure of what is going wrong, although I'm pretty sure it's something wrong with the CSS. Here's my code:

```
<html> 

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
    <title>Page 2</title>

    <style type="text/css">
    /* Your styles go here */
    img {width:200px; height:100px; animation-name: widthChange; animation-duration: 3s;}
    .loaded {animation-name: widthChange; animation-duration: 3s;}
    p {text-align:center}
    button {margin:20px}

    @keyframes widthChange {
        from {width: 200px;}
        to {width: 400px;}
    }

    </style>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
       // jQuery methods go here...
       $(document).ready(function() {
        $('img').addClass("loaded");
       });

    });
    /* Your additional JavaScript goes here */
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <img class = "image" src="elephant.jpg" alt="elephant"/>
    <p><button>Button 1</button><button>Button 2</button><button>Button 3</button></p>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with this code that is supported by all browsers: [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/yjqkkbdg/)

```
img {
    width:200px; 
    height:100px; 
    animation-name: widthChange; 
    animation-duration: 3s;
    -webkit-animation-name: widthChange; 
    -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
    -moz-animation-name: widthChange; 
    -moz-animation-duration: 3s;
    -0-animation-name: widthChange; 
    -0-animation-duration: 3s;    
}
p {text-align:center}
button {margin:20px}

@-webkit-keyframes widthChange {
    from {width: 200px;}
    to {width: 400px;}
}
@-o-keyframes widthChange {
    from {width: 200px;}
    to {width: 400px;}
}
@-moz-keyframes widthChange {
    from {width: 200px;}
    to {width: 400px;}
}
@keyframes widthChange {
    from {width: 200px;}
    to {width: 400px;}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to define vendor prefixes (at the time of writing) for webkit browsers, see [support information](http://caniuse.com/#search=animation). Correct definition would look like this:

```js
$(function () {
    $('img').addClass("loaded");
});
```

```css
img {
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
}
.loaded {
    -webkit-animation: widthChange 3s;
    animation: widthChange 3s;
}
p {
    text-align:center
}
button {
    margin:20px
}
@-webkit-keyframes widthChange {
    from {
        width: 200px;
    }
    to {
        width: 400px;
    }
}
@keyframes widthChange {
    from {
        width: 200px;
    }
    to {
        width: 400px;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="image" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" alt="elephant" />
```

If you want the image to preserve final state after the end of animation you can add `animation-fill-mode: forwards;`:

```
-webkit-animation: widthChange 3s forwards;
```

Answer (score 0):

At first animation-name is an experimental technology as you can check here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-name

Second, every animation needs keyframes, which you don't have in your code, you can try using css transitions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions